# How to make hist2d xaxis ticks as datetime format?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, histogram

I want to convert unixtime to datetime format to display the following data with hist2d.
However, everytime I convert unixtime to datetime

I got "TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''"

The data I want to plot:

[image: The data I want to display]

This is what I plotted if I put unixtime as xsticks:

[image: This is what I plotted if I put unixtime as xsticks]

This is the plot supposed to be
[image: This is supposed to be]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

# example data
x = df_1['unix_time']
y = df_1['bid_ask_spread']

# Set up x_ticks
time_frame = np.linspace(1575254259187, 1575513459187, 73)
x_ticks = []
for i in time_frame:
    x_ticks.append(to_datetime(i))

# make a custom colormap with transparency
ncolors = 256
color_array = plt.get_cmap('YlOrRd')(range(ncolors))
color_array[:, -1] = np.linspace(0, 1, ncolors)
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(name='YlOrRd_alpha', colors=color_array)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(16,9), dpi=80)

ax1.hist2d(x, y, bins=[71, 81], cmap=cmap, edgecolor='white')

# ax1.set_xticks(x_ticks[::5])
ax1.set_ylim(bottom=0)

plt.show()
```

Comment: `matplotlib.dates.DateLocator()`?

Comment: I will try. Still looking for answers, thank you!

Comment: not an answer, but these do not look like unix_timestamps. `1575254280000` corresponds to sometime in the year 51887. Are you from the future?

Comment: @DizietAsahi Lol. Sorry, I forgot to mention that this is the unix_time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My feeling is that you would need to use `numpy.histogram2d` to compute the histogram, then convert the edges in `datetime` format, and finally plot the histogram vs. the converted coordinates.

```
# Test data
N = 2*24*60
df = pd.DataFrame({'unix_time':pd.date_range(start='2018-02-01', freq='1min', periods=N).strftime('%s').astype(int),
                   'value':np.random.normal(size=(N,))})

# compute the 2D histogram using numpy
H,xedges,yedges = np.histogram2d(df['unix_time'], df['value'], bins=[24,10])
# convert the x-edges into datetime format
to_datetime = np.vectorize(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)
xedges_datetime = to_datetime(xedges)

# plot the two cases side by side
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8,3))
ax1.hist2d(df['unix_time'],df['value'], bins=[24,10])
ax1.set_title('unix_time')

ax2.pcolor(xedges_datetime, yedges, H.T)
ax2.set_title('datetime')
# pretty up the xaxis labels
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)


fig.autofmt_xdate()
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]